# AngularJS ui router (resolve part)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wrote ui.router to get data from JSON file. 
I am not getting error messages, but code does not enter "resolve" part. 
So I cannot get data from JSON file.

Can anyone tell me what could possibly make this happen and the way to fix it?

Here is my code.
    (function(){

```
/*
 * Declaration of main angular module for this application.
 *
 * It is named turtleFacts and has no dependencies (hence the 
 * empty array as the second argument)
 */
angular
    .module('GrammarQuiz', ['ui.router'])
    .config(
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        console.log('HOLY SMOKES, I CAN BREATHE IN HERE')
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/1');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home',{
            url: "/#/testtest",

            resolve: {
                questions: function($http){
                    console.log('!!#@!#@!');
                    return $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'api/data1.json'
                    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                        console.log('thisi now working!!!!');
                    })
                }
            }
        })
     })
```

})();

Comment: Try adding a success method to the $http promise that returns the data from the response.

Comment: Also, using .success and .error for $http promises is deprecated. I would recommend using .then

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have to return the value you want from the $http callbacks:

```
resolve: {
    questions: function($http) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/data1.json'
        }).success(function(data) {
            return data; // this is what you're missing
        }).error(function() {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
}
```

But you should really use .then instead of .success and .error

```
resolve: {
    questions: function($http) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/data1.json'
        }).then(function success(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function error(response) {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change question: function ($http)... to

```
question: ['$http', fucntion($http) {..}]
```

Comment: just using `function($http) {}` should work just fine since the parameter `$http` is the same as the actual name of the $http service.